# Jira JQL to filter on issues that are not part of a particular fixVersion

Tags: jira, jql

I can use `fixVersion = R3` to find all JIRA issues that have been marked with `R3` as Fix Version(s), but if I try `fixVersion != R3` then it is missing a lot of issues for some reason.

Are `=` and `!=` not complementary operators in JQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind, I figured it out, the negation of

```
fixVersion = R3
```

is

```
fixVersion != R3 or fixVersion is EMPTY
```